Apache EntityUtils.toString() timeouts for big response
We have deployed our code in AWS lambda. I am using EntityUtils to get string response body.  But it gets timeout for big json response string. Total characters in json response is 6266832
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

By checking other solutions in stack overflow, I have tried multiple ways. But still getting timeout exception.
Solution 1 : Added socket timeout exception
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(180000).setConnectTimeout(180000).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

Solution 2 : Getting input stream and convert to string
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
        String content = null;
        if(entity != null) {
            try(InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent()) {
                content = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Execption in getting content from Response=" + e);
            }
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

Solution 3 : Using BasicResponseHandler
String content = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(resp);

All the above solutions are not working for me.
Can anyone please suggest better approach for to get string from EntityUtils?

Increase the timeout?

@assylias, I have increased the timeout. still getting issue

Which timeout? Where are you seeing it? Share the error message, and full exception stack if any. Why do you need the response as a String?
